# Who is the third Kang variant in this image?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

In the post-credits scene for *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, we witness

> a trio of Kang variants discussing the death of the exiled Kang. They then walk out to an arena full of Kang variants, but it would seem that these three are in a position of authority over the others.
>  [image]

I can identify two of them from their costumes, but can't figure out who the third is. So, from left to right, we have:

1. Rama-Tut - a younger variant who went back and ruled ancient Egypt.
2. Immortus - an older variant who is the self-appointed guardian of time.
3. ???

Could the third one be the MCU version of Iron Lad? That's the only one I came up with that fits the outfit, although Iron Lad should be a teenager and his armor should look like Iron Man's.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the director, Peyton Reed, that third variant is based on [Scarlet Centurion](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nathaniel_Richards_(Scarlet_Centurion)_(Earth-6311)), a character from the comics who first appeared in *[Avengers Annual Vol. 1 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Annual_Vol_1_2)* (July 9, 1968).

> We definitely wanted to recreate that and give Jonathan [Majors] a starting point to deal with, 'Who do we bring in of the variants?' **There's Rama Tut and there's a character based on Scarlet Centurion and, of course, Immortus.** We wanted to go full Kurasawa Ran with it and make it really operatic.
>
> <sub>[Ant-Man And The Wasp: Quantumania Director Reveals Credits Scenes Secrets (Exclusive)](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania-credits-scenes-director-interview/)</sub>

According to the producer, Stephen Broussard, the filmmakers referred to him simply as '[Centurion](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Centurion).'

> Three members of the Council are most prominent in the scene and seemingly in charge, two of whom are more obviously the MCU incarnations of notable Kang identities Rama-Tut and Immortus. **The third isn’t quite as obvious at a glance but Broussard said that they had referred to him as Centurion, a nod to the Scarlet Centurion identity Kang used in the comics.**
>
> <sub>[Quantumania Filmmakers on the Ending, Kang’s Future, and Ant-Man’s New Secret](https://www.fandom.com/articles/ant-man-quantumania-spoilers-kang-avengers-modok)</sub>

Note that the movie version doesn't bear much of a visual resemblance to the comics version.

> [image: Image of Scarlet Centurion from Avengers Annual Vol. 1 #2, page 38 (July 9, 1968).]
>
> <sub>*Avengers Annual Vol. 1 #2* (July 9, 1968)</sub>

Comment: Good find - I never would've guessed Scarlet Centurion.

Comment: For anyone else wondering what on Earth a "Kurosawa Ran" is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ran_(film).